# findViewById returrns null from searchView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to remove the unnderline from the searchView but the findViewById method returns null all the time

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    View view = mSearchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Init your SearchView in your `onCreate`

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    searchView = findViewById(R.id.search);
    View v = searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

}
```

The layout  `R.layout.activity_main`

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: i find out why now, i had improt the android.widget.SearchView but trying to use it as android.support.v7.widget.SearchView,but thx any way